# Visual C# verbatim string syntax problem

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to create a string literal in visual C sharp. i don't know why VS is throwing errors about the html test i have inserted the @ "" should allow multi line and be literal from what i have read, what am i doing wrong?

```
string test = @" 

        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>

        <style type="text/css">
                        body{font-family:helvetica;}
                        body{font-size:10px;}
                        table{ border-collapse:collapse; } 
                        table{border:2px solid black; }
                        table{font-family:helvetica;}
                        table{font-size:17px;}
                        td{border:1px solid #D2B9D3;}
                        td{font-family:helvetica;}
                        td{font-size:18px;}
                        th{border:1px solid black;}
                        .style4 {font-size: 36px}
        </style>

        </head>

        ";
```

Comment: Perhaps because you have double quotes in your string.

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "c sharp". The language is named "C#".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to replace " to "" in your html text and it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  I just read further on and yes it seems that "" is the correct route since it's a verbatim string.

<strike>Actually `""` is a VB.NET thing, in C# you will want `\"` to escape the quotes.</strike>

Here are some others, for your reference.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx

Comment: maybe one more question, i know how to do it in Powershell scripting, but how can i insert a string variable within the @" ";

Comment: You'll have to do it in two separate steps, as the @" " is completely literal inside.

Comment: To clarify @"foo" + myString + @"bar"

Answer (score 0):

I found that using ' in place of " also works for your specific situation.

```
@"<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>"
```